# Horizontal distance between circle and ellipse centered at origin

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

The figure below shows a circle of radius $r$, centered at the origin of cartesian coordinates, and an inclined ellipse also centered at the origin, with semiaxes $a$ and $b$. The area of the circle and that of the ellipse are identical, such that $r^2 = ab$.
I need to know the horizontal distance between points $P$ and $Q$, which is exactly the coordinate $x$ of point $Q$. I am interested in knowing if there is a way to relate that coordinate with the semiaxes of the ellipse. I know graphically that $a-b=x$, but I can't find a way to demonstrate it algebraically.
The angle between the $x$ coordinate axis and the mayor axis of the ellipse is unknown. 
Also $Q$ is the point on the ellipse where $y$ is a maximum, equal to the radius $r$. The shape of the ellipse will vary according to its inclination, such that when the inclination angle approaches zero, $a$ increases and $b$ decreases, while the relationship $y=r$ always is maintained
[image]

Comment: @NickD $Q$ may be defined as point $P$ being translated horizontally a distance $x$. Also it is the point on the ellipse where $y$ is a maximum, equal to the radius $r$.

Comment: There is a relationship between the inclination and the shape of the ellipse. If you approach the inclination to zero degrees, $a$ increases and $b$ decreases such that the "height" of the ellipse, thus the value of $y$, is always $r$.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited the post

Comment: You mean "$a$ decreases and $b$ increases..."? At inclination 0, the ellipse becomes the circle, correct?

Comment: No, the inclination is the angle between the major axis and the $x$ coordinate.

Comment: Yes, and as that gets smaller (i.e. the ellipse becomes more horizontal), $a$ shrinks and $b$ increases. When the inclination is 0, both $a$ and $b$ are equal to $r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O=(0,0)$ and $A$ the intersection of the ellipse with positive $x$-axis. Then $OA$ and $OQ$ are, by definition, [conjugate semi-diameters](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ConjugateDiameters.shtml) of the ellipse, and thus have the following nice properties:
$$
area_{AOQ}={1\over2}ab
\quad\text{and}\quad
OA^2+OQ^2=a^2+b^2.
$$
The first equality implies $OA=r$.
Substituting this and $OQ^2=x^2+r^2$ into the second equality yields:
$$
x^2=a^2+b^2-2r^2=a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the answer I was looking for, I knew there had to be some relationship that I was unaware of, thanks again for the help!